# 'data parameter is nil', error occured when accessing HTTP web services in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection

I'm New to iPhone application development, I'm facing the following Error rarely when making API Calls. Most of the time i'm getting the correct response from the server server. But Sometimes i'm facing the following error. I have checked there is no fault with the url.

Thanks in advance., Can anyone please share your knowledge to access API call without this Bug.

Here is my code

```
- (NSDictionary *) makeAPICall :(NSString *) url withParameters:(NSString *) parameters
{
    NSDictionary *resposeDataDict = nil;

    //Check the inernet connection
    if([self isInternetConnected]){
        NSLog(@"-----------------------------------------------------------------------");
        NSLog(@"URL : %@",url);
        NSLog(@"Parameters : %@", parameters);

        //SHOW LOADING ICON
        [self showLoading];
        NSData *responseData;
        NSString *encodeParameterString = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(                                                                                                                                                                                                    NULL,
                                                                                                                (__bridge CFStringRef) parameters,
                                                                                                                NULL,
                                                                                                                CFSTR("!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]\" "),
                                                                                                                kCFStringEncodingUTF8));

        NSString *postParametersString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"&data=%@", encodeParameterString];
        NSData *postData = [postParametersString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];

        responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

        NSError* error;
        resposeDataDict =  [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];

        NSLog(@"Response : %@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
        NSLog(@"-----------------------------------------------------------------------");

        //HIDE LOADING ICON
        [self hideLoading];

     }
     else{
            [self showAlert:[resposeDataDict objectForKey:@"API Faled!"]];
     }

    }
    else{
         [self showAlert:@"Please Check your Internet Connection...!"];
    }

    return resposeDataDict;

}
```

I'm facing the following error.

My Input Parameters :

> {"page":"2","auth_token":"MTQzNzIwNzgxNElEQVNLSkhEQUpLU0RIQVNEMjExNg=="}
>   2015-07-18 14:45:13.129 PjtName[46309:1882277] *** Terminating app due
>   to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data
>   parameter is nil'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x273535f7 0x34a89c77 0x2735353d 0x2800574b 0x85fc9 0xbd2cd 0xbcd89 0x23c9cb 0x244661 0x23c9b7 0x24e14d
>   0x23e59d 0x240247 0x27319631 0x27317d51 0x27264b31 0x27264943
>   0x2e61d051 0x2a85a6f1 0xa042d 0x35025aaf) libc++abi.dylib: terminating
>   with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

Comment: Do you need to encode your string? I think, you should append your parameter variable with data and convert that to NSData object. Which solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving that error because the response that comes from the server is empty and the `NSJSONSerialization` class cannot work with a nil `NSData`.

To avoid the crash, sorrund the json parsing with the following condition:

```
NSError* error;
if (responseData != nil) {
     resposeDataDict =  [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];
}
```

Then you have to investigate about why you get a nil response. The main cause with this kind of problem is in a server side exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSError *error;
    responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&error];
```

you should not put error and you'll see why you receive from server nil data and then you can check

```
   if(error){
         //return or re-make request
    }else{
         //handle received data
    }
```

Also, you could try using asynchronousRequest because SynchronousRequest locks interface until it receives response from server and on 3G requests might take longer and user experience becomes kinda ugly.